# sqlite-net like statement crashes

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
Global.db.Query<Cards>("select * from Cards where card_name like ?", nameTextBox.Text);
```

But I want to add % to both sides like this with the parameter value.

```
Global.db.Query<Cards>("select * from Cards where card_name like %?%", nameTextBox.Text);
```

But I'm throwing an error when I try to execute this.  Any ideas why its crashing when I use the like statement like this? I ran the same query in my sqlite admin program with the same database and the results came out like they should.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I want to add % to both sides like this with the parameter value.

So do it for the value itself, rather than decorating the parameter in the SQL:

```
Global.db.Query<Cards>("select * from Cards where card_name like ?",
    "%" + nameTextBox.Text + "%");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Global.db.Query<Cards>($"select * from Cards where card_name like %{nameTextBox.Text}%");
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future users understand your answer even better.

Comment: Here is standart interpolation string.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated
This case is often helps to resolve problems with sql queries with specific params