# sqlite-net query with parameter that contains multi instructions

Tags: sql, parameters, sql-like, sqlite-net

I have a table with lots of information and now I want that a user can search that table.

```
List<Table> tableSearch = new List<Table>();
string[] words = searchString.Split(' ');
string sqlSearch = "";
foreach (string word in words)
{
    sqlSearch += " and Searchstring LIKE "+ "'%" + word + "%'";
}
tableSearch = db.Query<Table> ("select * from Table WHERE 1 = 1" + sqlSearch);
```

This is working and the solution I want to get to.
The problem is, that when the searchString is something like `Dü`, `D'` I get an exception.

I found here [sqlite-net like statement crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705558/sqlite-net-like-statement-crashes) a good solution for the problem.

My problem is, that the only solution I found for now is something like:

```
if (words.Length < 2) 
    tableSearch = db.Query<Table> ("select * from Table WHERE Searchstring LIKE ?", "%" + words[0] + "%");
else if (words.Length < 3) 
    tableSearch = db.Query<Table> ("select * from Table WHERE Searchstring LIKE ? and Searchstring LIKE ?", "%" + words[0] + "%", "%" + words[1] + "%");
```

and so on......

but this is not the solution I want.

Someone got an Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the special characters that makes an error in SQL string
For example the ' character need to be replaced with '' in SQL string. So, we need to modify your code to be like that.

```
List<Table> tableSearch = new List<Table>();
string[] words = searchString.Split(' ');
string sqlSearch = "";
foreach (string word in words)
{
    sqlSearch += " and Searchstring LIKE "+ "'%" + word.Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
}
tableSearch = db.Query<Table> ("select * from Table WHERE 1 = 1" + sqlSearch);
```

To know more about how to escape special characters please refer to the following link
[How does one escape special characters when writing SQL queries?](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries)

Comment: Thank's M.Nagy for the advice. I know about the problems with escaping and that the problem came from that.
I was wondering if there isn't a easier way to get it working, with this I still have to check and Replace every single special character (ä,ü,ö and so on).

Comment: You don't have to escape every (ä,ü,ö and so on), you only need to escape characters that make a syntax error like ' and characters that have a special meaning in SQL. But, the characters you mentioned above should works fine in the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I cant offer advice about the issue where the accented "Du" is concerned, but D' causes an error because the ' isnt escaped, and it interferes with the sql; accordingly in your first code block,

replace

```
sqlSearch += " and Searchstring LIKE "+ "'%" + word + "%'";
```

with

```
sqlSearch += " and Searchstring LIKE '%" + word.Replace("'","''") + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of writing N.Nagy 's answer, with less string joins:

```cs
        var words = (IEnumerable<string>)searchString.Split(' ').ToList();
        const string SqlClause = "Searchstring LIKE '%{0}%'";
        words = words.Select(word => string.Format(SqlClause, word.Replace("'", "''")));
        var joined = string.Join(" AND ", words.ToArray());
        const string SqlQuery = "select * from Table WHERE {0}";
        var tableSearch = db.Query<Table>(string.Format(SqlQuery, joined));
```

Because everybody should know about `string.Join()!!`

And just for giggles:

```cs
        const string SqlClause = "Searchstring LIKE '%{0}%'";
        const string SqlQuery = "select * from Table WHERE {0}";
        var tableSearch = db.Query<Table>(string.Format(SqlQuery, string.Join(" AND ", searchString.Split(' ').Select(word => string.Format(SqlClause, word.Replace("'", "''"))).ToArray())));
```

:)